# Command line to disable trackpad on Macbook Pro 15 w/ Touchbar

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro

I often need to switch between ignoring and not ignoring trackpad when an external mouse is connected. It's pretty annoying to do so through preference. So I decide to write a simple script to do that. After some research online, looks like people are suggesting something like

```
[~] on jiesiluo-mbp at 23:28:58
➜ sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleMultitouchDriver.kext                                                                                                                                                                     
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver; services 
failed to terminate - 0xdc008018.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver - (libkern/kext) 
kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

As you can see from the output, it doesn't really work because this kext is referenced by some other kexts as well. I don't fully understand what are the other extensions but they look important. I don't really want to touch them (some of them have index 1 3 4 5).

After some other research I find that even with "Ignore touchpad when external mouse is connected" checked, this Multitouch kext is unloaded neither. So here's my question: is there an equivalent under command line as checking this option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have Linux Mint 18 installed with kernel 4.4.0-45. I did the following to make it easy to toggle the touchpad state.

`sudo apt-get install xinput`

`xinput -list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ **FTE1001:00 0B05:0101**               ***id=14***   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

- Look for the id of the touchpad, in my case it's 14. I wrote a small shell script to turn the touchpad off and on.
- TouchPad off:

  `cd /usr/local/bin`
  `sudo nano touchpad-off`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # touchpad off
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
  echo touchpad off
  ```
- TouchPad on:

  `sudo nano touchpad-on`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # touchpad on
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
  echo touchpad on
  ```
- Make the scripts executable with:

  ```
  chmod +x touchpad-off
  chmod +x touchpad-on
  ```

  Now you can easily toggle the touchpad state with `touchpad-off` and `touchpad-on` in your terminal.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.